# Bayes Classifier Training set

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, bayesian

I am working on a simple naive bayes classifier and I had a conceptual question about it.

I know that the training set is extremely important so I wanted to know what constitutes a good training set in the following example. Say I am classifying web pages and concluding if they are relevant or not. The factors on which this decision is based takes into account the probabilities of certain attributes being present on that page. These would be certain keywords that increase the relevancy of the page. The keywords are apple, banana, mango. The relevant/irrelevant score is for each user. Assume that a user marks the page relevant/irrelevant equally likely.

Now for the training data, to get the best training for my classifier, would I need to have the same number of relevant results as irrelevant results? Do I need to make sure that each user would have relevant/irrelevant results present for them to make a good training set? What do I need to keep in mind?

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly endless topic as there are millions of factors involved. Python is a good example as it drives most of goolge(for what I know). And this brings us to the very beginning of google-there was an interview with Larry Page some years ago who was speaking about the search engines before google-for example when he typed the word "university", the first result he found had the word "university" a few times in it's title.

Going back to naive Bayes classifiers - there are a few very important key factors - assumptions and pattern recognition. And relations of course. For example you mentioned apples - that could have a few possibilities. For example:
Apple - if eating, vitamins, and shape is present we assume that the we are most likely talking about a fruit.
If we are mentioning electronics, screens, maybe Steve Jobs - that should be obvious.
If we are talking about religion, God, gardens, snakes - then it must have something to do with Adam and Eve.

So depending on your needs, you could have a basic segments of data where each one of these falls into, or a complex structure containing far more details. So yes-you base most of those on plain assumptions. And based on those you can create a more complex patterns for further recognition-Apple-iPod, iPad -having similar pattern in their names, containing similar keywords, mentioning certain people-most likely related to each other.

Irrelevant data is very hard to spot-at this very point you are probably thinking that I own multiple Apple devices, writing on a large iMac, while this couldn't be further from the truth. So this would be a very wrong assumption to begin with. So the classifiers themselves must make a very good segmentation and analysis before jumping to exact conclusions.

Comment: If my data is separated by user (ie, user_id has a related set of pages they searched which are then ranked relavent or not) would i need to build the training set around users who have both types of pages in their profile? or does it make a difference?

Comment: So you are using relational databases? Depending on the scale of things, you might want to choose a different approach, much like everyone seems to do these days. For instance I use couchbase at work, which is a document-oriented database. I admit-it's horrifying in terms of setup and configuration but in terms of reliability and scalability. That would also allow you to build training sets within their profiles.

Comment: The database is not in my control unfortunately. Can you suggest what i can do with the resources available to me?

Comment: Well your main task would be organize everything in such a way that it will be both sustainable, manageable and scalable. Planning, planning planning and unit testing. You won't be able to get anywhere without those for whatever it is you are trying to do-as I can see you intend to make something complex.